# JS последний объект массива getElementByClassName

Tags: javascript

Есть HTML

```
<div class="why">
    <div class="why__slide why__slide-active"></div>
    <div class="why__slide"></div>
    <div class="why__slide"></div>
    <div class="why__slide"></div>
</div>
<button class="why__button-left" id="why-left-button">назад</button>
<button class="why__button-right" id="why-right-button">вперед</button>
```

Есть код JS

```
let slides = document.getElementsByClassName('why__slide');
let slideActive = document.querySelector('.why__slide-active');
let index = 0;

whyPageRightButton.addEventListener('click', moveRight);

function moveRight(p){
    if (slides[index] != slides[index].length) {
        slides[index].classList.remove('why__slide-active');
        slides[++index].classList.add('why__slide-active');
    }
    else {
        slides[0].classList.add('why__slide-active');
    }
}

whyPageLeftButton.addEventListener('click', moveLeft);

function moveLeft(){
    slides[index].classList.remove('why__slide-active');
    slides[index-1].classList.add('why__slide-active');
}
```

сейчас когда мы щелкаем по правой кнопке мы переключаем класс `why__page-active` на следующий div. Но когда доходим до последнего, мы должны снова переключиться на первый div в списке, я не понимаю что я делаю не так, прошу помочь с объяснением на примере этого кода на чистом JS

и также когда мы нажимаем на кнопку назад, мы переключаемся только на один div назад, видимо это происходит потому что `index = 0`. Пожалуйста разжуйте что я делаю не так, сутки в интернете пока не понимаю

Comment: slides[index] != slides[index].length  а что это  если не ошибаюсь то это div  и длина div

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function moveRight(p) {
  slides[index].classList.remove('why__slide-active');
  index = Math.min(index + 1, slides.length - 1);
  slides[index].classList.add('why__slide-active');
}

function moveLeft() {
  slides[index].classList.remove('why__slide-active');
  index = Math.max(0, index - 1);
  slides[index].classList.add('why__slide-active');
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, не мог бы объяснить что делает index = Math.max(0, index - 1);

и когда доходит до последнего блока вправо, все равно не переходит на первый и не останавливается, в консоле выдает ошибку

Comment: @BigD Пардон, "off-by-one error" ). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

Answer (score 1):

Поведение функций `moveRight` и `moveLeft` должно быть аналогичным:

На примере `moveRight`

1. убрать класс active с элемента по текущему индексу
2. увеличить индекс на 1
3. если индекс == slides.length сбросить индекс в 0
4. установить класс active элементу по текущему индексу

В коде это может выглядеть так:

```
function moveRight(){
    slides[index].classList.remove('why__slide-active');
    index = index + 1;
    if (index == slides.length) {
        index = 0;
    }
    slides[index].classList.add('why__slide-active');
}
```

`moveLeft` выглядит аналогично.

```js
var whyPageRightButton = document.getElementById('why-right-button');
var whyPageLeftButton = document.getElementById('why-left-button');
let slides = document.getElementsByClassName('why__slide');
let index = 0;

whyPageRightButton.addEventListener('click', moveRight);

function moveRight() {
  slides[index].classList.remove('why__slide-active');
  index = index + 1;
  if (index == slides.length) {
    index = 0;
  }
  slides[index].classList.add('why__slide-active');
}

whyPageLeftButton.addEventListener('click', moveLeft);

function moveLeft() {
  slides[index].classList.remove('why__slide-active');
  index = index - 1;
  if (index == -1) {
    index = slides.length - 1;
  }
  slides[index].classList.add('why__slide-active');
}
```

```css
.why__slide {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.why__slide-active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="why">
  <div class="why__slide why__slide-active"></div>
  <div class="why__slide"></div>
  <div class="why__slide"></div>
  <div class="why__slide"></div>
</div>
<button class="why__button-left" id="why-left-button">назад</button>
<button class="why__button-right" id="why-right-button">вперед</button>
```

Также можно вообще не использовать индекс, а оперировать только активным элементом.

1. Сохранить `document.getElementsByClassName('why__slide-active')` в список. Так как коллекция живая, в ней всегда будет текущий активный элемент.
2. В обработчиках событий нужно взять этот элемент, он всегда будет нулевым в коллекции, так как всего один активный элемент.
3. удалить класс active
4. В случае `right` - нужно проверить у элемента [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/NonDocumentTypeChildNode.nextElementSibling)
5. если он отсутствует, значит дошли до конца, и нужно взять первый элемент, сделать это можно вызвав [`firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild)
6. добавить класс active

В случае `left` проверяются [`previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling) и [`lastElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/lastElementChild) соответственно.

Пример:

```js
var whyPageRightButton = document.getElementById('why-right-button');
var whyPageLeftButton = document.getElementById('why-left-button');
let activeSlides = document.getElementsByClassName('why__slide-active');

whyPageRightButton.addEventListener('click', moveRight);

function moveRight() {
  var activeSlide = activeSlides[0];
  activeSlide.classList.remove('why__slide-active');
  var nextActive = activeSlide.nextElementSibling || activeSlide.parentNode.firstElementChild;
  nextActive.classList.add('why__slide-active');
}

whyPageLeftButton.addEventListener('click', moveLeft);

function moveLeft() {
  var activeSlide = activeSlides[0];
  activeSlide.classList.remove('why__slide-active');
  var nextActive = activeSlide.previousElementSibling || activeSlide.parentNode.lastElementChild;
  nextActive.classList.add('why__slide-active');
}
```

```css
.why__slide {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.why__slide-active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="why">
  <div class="why__slide why__slide-active"></div>
  <div class="why__slide"></div>
  <div class="why__slide"></div>
  <div class="why__slide"></div>
</div>
<button class="why__button-left" id="why-left-button">назад</button>
<button class="why__button-right" id="why-right-button">вперед</button>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! уверен этот пример поможет многим